# select every 3rd number from the excel column

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2013

I have a excel worksheet with the one column (9000 value) and i want to have every 3rd value of the column. Or is it possible to have a command which gives the average of every 3 value ?

Answer (score 3):

You can use an array formula to loop through your range and pick out every third value. Something like this will work, assuming your values are in cells **A1:A9000**:

```
 =AVERAGE(IF(MOD(ROW(A1:A9000),3)=0,A1:A9000,""))
```

But after inserting the formula, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> rather than just <kbd>Enter</kbd>. This confirms it as an *array* formula and you will see in the formula bar that curly brackets have been placed around the formula - at which point it will look like this:

```
{=AVERAGE(IF(MOD(ROW(A1:A9000),3)=0,A1:A9000,""))}
```

Comment: @parth_bhimani did this answer your question?